# How to know when Ajax function is complete and all affected elements fully loaded?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following code which (amount other things) gets an image URL from the server:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'Script.php',
        data: {action: 'Random'},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            var results = data.slice(0,-1).split('|');
            var workers = [];
            for(i=0; i<results.length; i++)
            {
                workers[i] = workers[i].split(',');
            }
            for(i=0; i<workers.length; i++)
            {
                var j = i+1
                $('#random-worker' + j + '-pic').attr("src", workers[i][3]);
                $('#random-worker' + j + '-name').html(workers[i][0]);
                $('#random-worker' + j + '-pro').html(workers[i][1]);
                $('#random-worker' + j + '-city').html(workers[i][2]);
            }
        }
    });
```

Also, I have this code to display a loading gif while the ajax requests process

```
var $loading = $('.div-loading').hide();
    $(document)
        .ajaxStart(function () {
        $loading.show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        $loading.hide();
    });
```

What happens is that the Ajax is completed and the $loading div is hidden and only then the elements gets their values and the Image gets the new source. Is there a way to completely end the loading process and only then hide the $loading div?

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery AJAX provides a `.done()` method.

Comment: Shouldn't `var $loading = $('.div-loading').hide();` be `var $loading = $('.div-loading');` since you are showing it and hiding it at another point?

Comment: The $('.div-loading').hide() hides the element at the first place. I am showing it only when ajax calls are being made. thanks

Comment: Jay, thank you for the quick response but i found this note: "As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success()." am i mistaken and shouldn't i use success? thanks